CS9236 Compiling requires binding the lambda expression at least 100 times
I recently saw the following compiler message in C#:

CS9236 Compiling requires binding the lambda expression at least 100 times. Consider declaring the lambda expression with explicit parameter types, or if the containing method call is generic, consider using explicit type arguments.

Unfortunately, the help link is (currently) broken. Can you please explain this with examples? And why it is a good idea to bloat expressions with explicit types?
An example taken from the test:
using System.Linq;
class Container
{
    public IEnumerable<Container> Items;
    public int Value;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Container>();
        _ = list.Sum(
            a => a.Items.Sum(
                b => b.Items.Sum(
                    c => c.Value)));
    }
}


Given that you're seeing the compiler message, presumably you can at least demonstrate the problem with an example? That would make the question much clearer.

There is a test for it: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/ea13488634f55c535d40613199b4accbd16b5517/src/Compilers/CSharp/Test/Semantic/Semantics/OverloadResolutionPerfTests.cs#L388-L419

@JonSkeet I do not want to solve a problem with a code. I just want to know what the error message means. Because I cannot find any documentation anywhere.

So have you actually seen this in your code? Or when you say "I recently saw the following compiler message" do you literally mean "when browsing the Roslyn source code"? It may well be a hugely obscure error that only actually comes up if you're debugging Roslyn itself. (It's talking about the performance of the compiler, after all.) Just building the code that's in the test with the "dotnet build" command doesn't prompt that error.

I saw it in a proprietary code that I can't share publicly. I've never seen a message like this before. It is (logically) neither an error nor a warning by default. So I'm just curious if anyone here knows more details about it.

"I saw it in a proprietary code that I can't share publicly." But can you reproduce it in non-proprietary code? The example in the test looked like you shouldn't need anything remotely confidential to reproduce it - but you may need to check the compiler settings etc. As I say, just building the code from the test doesn't produce those warnings for me, so there may be something more needed. It's hard to try to dig into explaining something without being able to reproduce it.

"As I say, just building the code from the test doesn't produce those warnings for me, so there may be something more needed."
But then the test would fail, wouldn't it?

PS: I see it in VS 17.11.5.

"But then the test would fail, wouldn't it?" That's why I expected to see a warning - but I don't. Which suggests it may be related to some configuration option. Have you tried compiling that code yourself? Do you see the warning? Do you see it in both VS and at the command line?

Aha - compiling that code in VS I see it in "messages" (but not warnings or errors). I still don't see anything when building from the command line. Now that I've finally got a repro, I'll see if I can explain it. (But we'd have avoided a lot of back and forth if you'd included code from the start and explained that it's only visible in VS...)

Please edit the question with the example, and then I'll vote to reopen.

A simple high-level explanation is provided in the PR (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/72823) by Charles Stoner:
"... which may occur when the lambda expression is nested and used as an argument to a method call with multiple overloads"

TWIMC: The reason why "100" is explained in the source code (https://github.com/cston/roslyn/blob/5a3f6e866b4f43cae46c660800c95267aa3cb1cf/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Binder/Binder_Lambda.cs#L448-L458):
"The particular max value is arbitrary, but large enough so diagnostics should only be reported for lambda expressions used as arguments to method calls where the product of the number of applicable overloads for that method call and for overloads for any containing lambda expressions is large."

Yup. The basic answer here is "Both overload resolution and generic type inference are hard. When there are multiple overloads, and fulfilling one step of that process involves applying overload and generic type inference recursively, the complexity blows up quickly. Providing more information to the compiler via type arguments or explicit lambda parameter types reduces that complexity explosion."

I thought it would be great to have some examples with detailed explanation on SO. Because Google currently does not find anything relevant. And SO answers are usually highly ranked. But since the SO community closed the question, others will have to browse Roslyn code again...

There are two reopen votes (including mine). I'll answer the question if it ends up reopened. I suspect it wouldn't have been closed in the first place if you'd included the example from the start though.

@JonSkeet Weird, I cast the 3rd reopen vote about 30 minutes ago. And shows as open here

@phuzi: I suspect it was already reopen when I posted my comment, and I just didn't check :) (I guess I scrolled straight to the comments.) Time for an answer.

Firstly, as far as I can see these messages only show up in Visual Studio - there may well be a way to get dotnet build to report them, but I haven't found it yet.
The example can be simplified slightly, to only use two lambda expressions:
#pragma warning disable 649
class Container
{
    public IEnumerable<Container> Items;
    public int Value;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<Container>();
        _ = list.Sum(
            a => a.Items.Sum(
                b => b.Value));
    }
}

This only produces a single message, but it's easier to understand.
The message isn't about whether the code is valid or not - it's really just saying "Hey, this is causing the compiler a lot of work - you can make its life easier." That in turn could reduce compilation times in some cases.
The reason this happens is due to two of the hairiest aspects of C# (from a specification angle, and I suspect from a compiler implementation angle):

Generic type inference
Overload resolution

In particular, while most expressions in C# naturally have a type, for lambda expressions the compiler has to effectively see whether it can convert the given lambda expression into the candidate parameter type in order to check each overload for applicability. When there are nested lambdas, that means the whole process ends up blowing up exponentially.
The reason Sum causes this problem where (say) Select doesn't is that Sum has a lot of overloads - even if you cut out the overloads with more than one parameter.
The message is a little confusing for this example, because specifying lambda expression parameter types and type arguments doesn't help. This still gives the same message, for example:
_ = list.Sum<Container>(
    (Container a) => a.Items.Sum<Container>(
        (Container b) => b.Value));

Telling the compiler the target type of the lambda expression completely works though:
_ = list.Sum(
    a => a.Items.Sum(
        (Func<Container, int>) (b => b.Value)));

Or you might choose to implement it in a different way, with local variables:
var valueSelector = (Container b) => b.Value;
_ = list.Sum(
    a => a.Items.Sum(valueSelector));

or
Func<Container, int> valueSelector = b => b.Value;
_ = list.Sum(
    a => a.Items.Sum(valueSelector));

(Or use a local function.)
All of these basically make the compiler's life easier, potentially leading to shorter compilation times. If compilation time isn't a problem for you and you don't want to change your code, you can just suppress the message. The message is only there so that the compiler can help to explain why it's taking so long.
